# Is there any software to simulate a laboratory?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, software

I wanted to do some experiments with some chemicals but unfortunately I do not have access to them. Is there any software I can use to get the products?

I don't want to do very complicated things, I just want to gain some experience in basic chemistry, with simple chemicals like $\ce{H2O2}$, some salts, sulfuric acid, potassium permanganate, etc.

I tried to search on the net but most of the software I found is too complicated for me.

Do you know about any such software? Or do you have any alternatives?

Comment: [The Powder Toy](https://powdertoy.co.uk/) game is probably more fun than learning, but is IMO worth mentioning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a product called [Yenka Chemistry](https://yenka.com/en/Yenka_Chemistry/) which simulates basic chemicals/apparatus, and allows basic manipulations (for instance to show the pH change as more acid is added to base, or the amount of gas evolved).

The program evolved from another piece of software called Crocodile Clips, which was aimed at GCSE science in the United Kingdom. For this reason it is incredibly basic, mainly focusing on inorganic reactions (acid/base, titrations, reactivity of group 1 and 2 metals), with no real capacity for demonstrating organic reactions.

Comment: I just tried it right now, Its an awesome software!

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend standardizing on [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/). Mathematica is the best general software to do physics and chemistry. You can use Mathematica absolutely free from the web with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/). Instead of learning a specific chemistry program, if you learn Mathematica you can do *any* kind of science with it. Its the single most valuable tool you can learn to do math and science.

Here is an example, let's say you want to know what happens when you combine hydrochloric acid and calcium hydroxide. Just type it in to Wolfram Alpha:

[image]

It tells us the result: calcium chloride and water. Mathematica can do anything you would need to do in computational chemistry, stoichiometry, rate equations, molecular modeling, you name it.

Mathematica is free or inexpensive for students.

Comment: I had seen a trial version of mathematica but I did not know it could do reactions also. Can we also get the colors of compounds and weather the compound will dissolve or precipitate?

Comment: No, but both the color and solubility of common compounds can be found on the Wikipedia.

Comment: Don't get your hopes up too high. Wolfram Alpha's capabilities to list the products of chemical reactions are currently very limited. Fun idea, though.

Comment: I don't think Mathematica would be able to manipulate organic compounds at all...

Comment: Three years later, Mathematica is still about as good in chemistry as Photoshop in hydrodynamics.